# Understanding deferring macro

Tags: c++, macros, deferred, preprocessor-directive

I am trying to understand the deferring macro hierarchy. Does this make sense?

```
// Online C++ compiler to run C++ program online
#include <iostream>
#define EMPTY()
#define EVAL_1(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define EVAL_2(...) EVAL_1(EVAL_1(__VA_ARGS__))

#define DEFER(...) __VA_ARGS__ EMPTY()
#define DEFER2(...) __VA_ARGS__ DEFER(EMPTY) ()
#define DEFER3(...) __VA_ARGS__ DEFER2(EMPTY) ()
#define DEFER4(...) __VA_ARGS__ DEFER3(EMPTY) ()
#define A(x) x

int main() {
    // The parameter is evaluated during expansion.
    std::cout << (EVAL_1(DEFER(A)(5)))<<std::endl; //line 1: evaluate(A (5)) = 5. Output = 5  
    //std::cout << (EVAL_1(DEFER2(A)(5)))<<std::endl; // line 2: evaluate(A EMPTY() (5)) = A(5), Output = error.
    //std::cout << (EVAL_1(DEFER3(A)(5)))<<std::endl; // line 3: evaluate(A EMPTY EMPTY() () (5)) = A EMPTY() (5), Output = error.
    //std::cout << (EVAL_1(DEFER4(A)(5)))<<std::endl; // line 4: evaluate(A EMPTY EMPTY EMPTY() () () (5)) = A EMPTY EMPTY () () (5), Output = error.

    
    std::cout << (EVAL_2(DEFER(A)(5)))<<std::endl; //line 5: evaluate(evaluate(5)) from line 1. Output = 5.
    std::cout << (EVAL_2(DEFER2(A)(5)))<<std::endl;//line 6: evaluate(evaluate(A(5))) = 5. Output =5
    std::cout << (EVAL_2(DEFER3(A)(5)))<<std::endl;//line 7: evaluate(evaluate(A EMPTY() (5)))=5.
    //std::cout <<(EVAL_2(DEFER4(A)(5)))<<std::endl;//line8: error

    return 0;
}
```

Are there any subtle features that I missed or misunderstood?

Comment: Have you looked at the preprocessed code to see how the macros are expanded?

Comment: And what are you trying to do? What is the problem these macros are supposed to solve? Why are you writing such macros? Or where did you get them from?

Comment: For those interested this seems to be the [source](https://github.com/pfultz2/Cloak/wiki/C-Preprocessor-tricks,-tips,-and-idioms), see the section 'Deferred expression'